# Problema con contenido Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Tengo este código y al compilar el mismo con una lista pequeña de datos funciona ok, el problema surge cuando la lista de entrada es mayor. Ahí no me arroja el resultado. Supuse que habría un error con algún `NaN` en el *DataFrame-, pero probé con `fillna(0)` y tampoco muestra resultado.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime
import os
import yfinance as yf
sp500 = pd.read_html('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_S%26P_500_companies')
    sp500_list = np.array(sp500[0]['Symbol'])
ticker = sp500_list.tolist()
```

Con la lista de `SP500` no funciona, si se modifica la lista `tiker` por la siguiente esta ok:

```py
ticker = ['ALLE','LNT','ALL','GOOGL','GOOG','MO','AMZN','AMCR','AEE','MCD']
acciones = yf.download(ticker,start="2019-01-01", end="2020-10-15").dropna()
spy = yf.download('SPY',start="2019-01-01", end="2020-10-15").dropna()
df=acciones['Close']

concatenated_df = pd.DataFrame()
row=0
rebalanceo = 60
for row in range(1,len(df),rebalanceo):
    if row < len(df)-rebalanceo:
        dc=[]
        buy = []
        sell = []
        for i in df.columns:
            dc.append(df[i].iloc[row]/df[i].iloc[row-20]-1 + df[i].iloc[row]/df[i].iloc[row-60]-1)
            buy.append(df[i].iloc[row])
            sell.append(df[i].iloc[row+rebalanceo])

        df_momentum = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['symbol', 'momentum','buy','sell','index'])
        df_momentum['symbol'] = df.columns
        df_momentum['momentum'] = dc
        df_momentum['buy'] = buy
        df_momentum['sell'] = sell
        df_momentum['date']=df.index[row]
        df_momentum.sort_values(by=['momentum'], ascending=False)


        df_momentum['orden'] = 1
        for i in range(1,len(df_momentum)):
            df_momentum['orden'].iloc[i]= i+1

        df_momentum.query('orden < 4', inplace=True)
        df_momentum['PL']=df_momentum['sell']/df_momentum['buy']-1

        concatenated_df=pd.concat([concatenated_df,df_momentum],ignore_index=True)     
        concatenated_df.head()
```

El resultado de `concatenated_df.head()` me muestra `_` mientras con los la lista de `tickers` acotada muestra el *DataFrame* sin problema

Comment: si no te muestra nada es por que no hay resultado, verifica bien las operaciones que haces

Comment: de hecho si tienes codigos NaN 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/WNM0g.png

pero al momento de mandar el dropna, por alguna razon elimina todos los registros